# Snap Chromium randomly flushing cache

Tags: 19.10, chromium, snap

I'm noticing a strange and annoying behavior in **snap Chromium**, running on **Ubuntu 19.10**.

It happens sometimes that, while using Chromium, its icon disappears from the side dock, only to reappear a few seconds later, but looking as if the application wasn't open (I'm not able to minimize/maximize the window from the tray).
At the same time, most visited sites completely disappear from the start tab, as well as all bookmark favicons.

It seems like it's flushing some cache, maybe there's some snap update process involved which is causing this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by snapd updating the chromium snap to a newer revision while it is running, and is a known issue tracked by [bug #1616650](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1616650). I recommend you enable the [refresh app awareness](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/wip-refresh-app-awareness/10736) experimental feature:

```
snap set core experimental.refresh-app-awareness=true
```

and then restart chromium. This will prevent automatic refreshes of snaps when an app of theirs is running (the current implementation actually delays the refresh, up to a maximum of 7 days, so the update will eventually be installed if the app hasn't been restarted in the meantime).

This experimental feature should eventually become stable and default. I am also working on [displaying a notification](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1864901) to prompt users to restart chromium when an update has been installed while running.